# jQuery not linking with HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning to program and have faced something that should be very simple but have taken me three days of frustration.

I can't seem to get the jQuery file to link with my html.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>

    <script src="/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
</head>     
    <body>
    <div class="heads">
        <div id="about">
            <p>About.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="work">
            <p>Work.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="contact">
            <p>Contact.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    });
});
```

It it not the final jQuery, but I was sure it was suppose to work.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: is your `jquery-2.0.3.min.js and script.js file in same directory with your html file?

Comment: One way to avoid problems like the one @Eray suggests is to inspect/debug your code, which is something you should learn if you're using JQuery and HTML. It'll save you those 3 days. Right click, inspect element on Chrome/Firefox + Firebug.

Comment: Your code assumes both .js files are at the site's document root. Is that true? When coding JavaScript, always leave your browser's error console open. Look in the network tab of the browser console - do you see the files being successfully downloaded?

Comment: Is that all the javascript you have? you have missed a `})`

Comment: Eray, Michael Berkowski: All the files are in the root folder. On another note: Is that a good or bad practise? 

Claudio Redi: Yes, at the moment, but thats more for testing. I have a bit bigger plans but want to iron out the basic mistakes.

Comment: @Hauk1 It's not a bad practice necessarily - depends on your need. You may quickly find it pays to place them into a directory as in `/js/script.js` just for organization.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So my practise is easier for smaller sites, but not best practise as my skills develop to bigger and more complex sites?

Comment: @Hauk1 It's fine for a small site - I personally never like seeing .js files littering a site document root, but there's nothing inherently wrong with it.  As you build bigger sites with more complex organization though, you'll find it helpful to group them somewhere. It is common to have an `/assets` directory which contains `/assets/images, /assets/css, /assets/js` or any other static files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
```

The path to your files is wrong. You don't use any subfolder. It should be:

```
<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

This fixed the problem for me :)
happy coding

Answer (score 3):

If that's your final code, then you're missing `})`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    }); // < -- This is missed
});
```

Assuming this is your problem, I recommend you to always use correct indentation. It really helps to easily detects these kind of problems.

Comment: That should be `})` not just `}` to close the `click()`

Comment: Not just that - }); is missed.

Comment: Hauk1, if you're not consistently indenting, I recommend it.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Thanks, It is not the final code, but more of an attempt to iron out some beginners mistakes. However it did not work. Added a Dropbox link to all my code if that helps.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xycou9k8o1ml0be/Gmr38YVLYn

Answer (score 0):

```
change the path to <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script> .
```

Comment: It seems he's using jQuery 2.0.3, while a CDN might be better, it's the wrong version. Please change it to reflect the original code in question.

Comment: @DaveChen There is no reason for why I'm using 2.0.3, other than its presence on the jQuery page. If there is any good reasons to change please elaborate on why.

Comment: If there are clients still using older versions of IE, you should respect that and use version one.